# How to set a default value of 0 in column for when new row is inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a user table which has a number of downloads column, how would i initialize it to be 0 for very new row. I only want it to change when i trigger an event in another table.

Comment: In your migrations, you can have something like `t.integer :sample, default: 0` or in your model a callback if it is a new record to do something like `self.sample ||= 0` in the callback method.

Comment: By default, the value would be `NULL`.  You can set the default value using the `DEFAULT` keyword in your `create table` statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but what if a value say 3 was inserted, the number of downloads would be 3, i want to stop from entering any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it to `0` using a default statement in the `create table` statement:

```
create table . . .
    numdownloads int default 0
```

You can also do this using an `alter table` statement after the table is created.

However, you don't really need to do this.  In your trigger you can do:

```
update user
    set numdownloads = coalesce(numdownloads, 0) + 1
```

to increment the value.

When you pull the data, you can use `coalesce()` to turn `NULL` into `0`:

```
select . . . , coalesce(numdownloads, 0) as numdownloads
from user
```

EDIT:

To stop a user from inserting any value, then use an insert trigger.  Alternatively, just calculate the value when you need it, instead of storing it as a counter.